# Why do we need galvanic isolation with low power components?

Tags: power-supply, adc, i2c, isolation, full-bridge

[image]

This is an analog to digital converter with I2C communication from a project (350W power supply) by ti instruments. it senses line and pfc voltage and communicates with the MCU. I don't understand what is the purpose of the digital isolators as we are dealing with low power components? Am I missing anything here?.

Also, what is the purpose of the inductors?

Comment: You just said that it senses line voltage. So presumably one side of it is connected to 240V or 120V, and the other side is connected to a 5V or 3.3V MCU. Also, 350W is not low power.

Comment: You wrote that this is from a TI project.  Is this from a reference design?  Could you post a link to the rest of the reference design?

Comment: @NickAlexeev sure. but i think you must log in with your ti account. 
https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup301/slup301.pdf
To get the detailed design search for “PMP5568”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is "primary side" and "secondary side" written around either side of the isolation barrier.  That suggests that this is an off-line (mains powered) power supply.  These power supplies are usually required to have galvanic isolation between primary and secondary.  This includes isolation of the primary power path as well as auxiliary power and small signals.

As you can see, the only thing between the main AC and the ADC are voltage dividers.

[image] (source: [p.28 in the slides](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup301/slup301.pdf))

The inductors on the right are chokes to reduce the common-mode noise on the signal lines.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing anything here?.

Yes. Mains voltage is *lethal*. The circuit measures and/or controls mains on the primary side *without* isolation. Protection of the MCU (And the user!) on the secondary side requires galvanic isolation from mains voltage.

You may also want to check where primary GND is connected to, it is probably *not* protected Earth (PE) but at a line level.